# Visual edit jquery knob

Tags: numbers, android-edittext, jquery-knob

I have a problem with the visual adaptation of the script. I would like to number in the middle looks like the one in the picture. Where is a different color and a `%` character in the end.

[image: Picture]

How I can edit it. I must do it on jquery.knob.js or on some other file like css?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a `%` symbol at the end of the count.

However, you can change the color code of the count by using the `inputColor` parameter.

Initialize the plugin as  -

```
$(".cs_knob").knob({
//other parameters-----
inputColor : '#34EB40', //Color of the count text
});
```

Below is a visual edit fiddle for the jQuery knob where you can play with all configurations -
http://bitconfig.com/jquery-knob/bitconfig_jquery_knob.html